# multiple instances of view helper plugin?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-view

How do I instantiate multiple instances of a view helper plugin in Zend 2?

I want to return a new instance every time I call `$this->pluginName();` from the view.

How do I return a new instance of the view plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the service name to the `getViewHelperConfig()` `shared` configuration key in `Module.php` and set this value to `false`

**Module.php**

```
function getViewHelperConfig()
{
  return array(
    'shared' => array(
      'MyViewHelper' => false,
    ),
    'factories' => array(
      'MyViewHelper' => 'App\View\Helper\MyViewHelperFactory',
    )
  );
}
```

By adding `'MyViewHelper' => false`, the service manager (or View Helper plugin manager) will create a new instance of that service each time it is used.

The [documentation states](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html#using-configuration)

> **shared** An array of service name/boolean pairs, indicating whether or not a service should be shared. By default, the ServiceManager assumes all services are shared, but you may specify a boolean false value here to indicate a new instance should be returned.

Comment: The answer is definitely correct! Unfortunately there currently seems to be an issue with this solution: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/4221#issuecomment-47195693

Comment: @Webdevilopers looking at `Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::__call()` I do think this is still a bug. [You can see it adds the helper to `__pluginCache` on the first call](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php#L396), then each subsequent call is then reusing this. It should *allways* try to fetch the plugin from the `ViewHelperManager` ([just like the `plugin()` method does](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php#L377)) as this will check the `shared` variable.

Comment: I think that is what weierophinney is looking for in the issue! Can you post it there too please?

Comment: I added your suggestion to the issue: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/4221#issuecomment-47750073

Comment: @Webdevilopers I checked out the latest branch to apply a fix but it has already been applied; I suggest you update.

Comment: Which branch do you mean, can you post the link? Strange because the issue is still discussed @AlexP .

Comment: @webDEVILopers An [update to this](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/6786#event-200184584) - 2.4 Should fix the issue.

Comment: Finally! :) @samsonasik