# ZF2 custom view helper shares variable across multiple elements - shared service issue?

Tags: zend-framework2, view-helpers, servicemanager, viewhelper

I successfully added a custom view helper with the following configuration:

https://gist.github.com/webdevilopers/b22f7471fd2b8d60cdea#file-module-php

The view helper has a custom variable named `foo`:

https://gist.github.com/webdevilopers/b22f7471fd2b8d60cdea#file-abstractformautocomplete-php

As I mentioned this setup works **fine as long as I have only a single element** using the view helper.

As soon as I add more than one form element the `setFoo` method gets only called once and the `foo` variable remains set throughout the following elements.

https://gist.github.com/webdevilopers/b22f7471fd2b8d60cdea#file-autocompleteform-php

I read about **Shared Services** in **ZF2** - is this such a case? How can I prevent this behaviour?

[Introduction to the Zend Framework 2 ServiceManager](http://blog.evan.pro/introduction-to-the-zend-framework-2-servicemanager)

[By default, the ServiceManager assumes all services are shared, but you may specify a boolean false value here to indicate a new instance should be returned.](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html#using-configuration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've basically answered your own question here. Services are shared by default, so the initial instance of your view helper is reused for subsequent calls unless you configure it otherwise. To do this, add the `shared` parameter to your view helper config (untested):

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'formelement'                  => 'Application\Form\View\Helper\FormElement',
            'formautocompletehidden'       => 'Application\Form\View\Helper\FormAutocompleteHidden'
        ),
        'shared' => array(
            'formelement' => false,
            'formautocompletehidden' => false
        ),
    );
}
```

**Edit:** as mentioned in the comments, this doesn't currently work for view helpers due to a bug in ZF2.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, @Tim Fountain. Your solution is obviously correct. I found a similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272055/multiple-instances-of-view-helper-plugin - Unfortunately it does not work. Is there a global parameter to set to make the service manager "allow" setting the `shared` entry?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you mean the view helpers are still not being shared? Presumably your actual code isn't just setting "foo", so  what does it really do and how are you testing whether or not the shared thing works?

Comment: As you can see the setFoo() method checks if $foo has already been set. When calling the view template with the two elements using the view helper I only get the first echo, the second time it is not called. Maybe there is some in-between class since I am passing the $element to that method. If the $element e.g. is a formText element should I add a shared=false entry for it too?

Comment: I should point out that the only reason I need to set shared service to false is the fact that methods like getFoo() check for an existing variable $foo to avoid unneccessary usage of setters. It's not critical yet because I could simply comment out the condition. I thought this was a good approach and it seemed like official #zf2 form elements did something similar:         if ($this->elementHelper) {
            return $this->elementHelper;
        }

Comment: @samsonasik has posted an issue on this: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/4221

Comment: I just tested this out and you're right, it doesn't work. As mentioned on the issue you linked, this is a bug in ZF I think.

Comment: I've added my example: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/4221#issuecomment-47195693 - Maybe this is the same issue.